# Share util jar file with war deployments in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Suppose I have a jar file called 'util.jar'. This jar file contains mostly JPA entities and some útil classes (no EJBs). How do I make this jar available to all wars deployed in Wildfly (without placing the jar inside the war's WEB-INF/lib)?

I thied to create a module in Wildfly:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="br.edu.ufca">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ufca.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and in my war MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Dependencies: br.edu.ufca export
```

but I'm getting all sorts of erros, like these:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module "br.edu.ufca:main" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module "br.edu.ufca:main" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module "br.edu.ufca:main" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:427)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/event/SystemEventListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.event.SystemEventListener from [Module "br.edu.ufca:main" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 31 more

15:12:16,710 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "email-servidores.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module \"br.edu.ufca:main\" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules,C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base)))
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module \"br.edu.ufca:main\" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules,C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base)))
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/edu/ufca/web/FalhaValidacaoParametroVisao (Module \"br.edu.ufca:main\" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules,C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base)))
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/event/SystemEventListener
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.event.SystemEventListener from [Module \"br.edu.ufca:main\" from local module loader @16e9adb (finder: local module finder @121714c (roots: C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules,C:\\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]"}}
15:12:16,745 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "email-servidores.war" (runtime-name : "email-servidores.war")
15:12:16,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores: Failed to start service

15:12:16,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:12:16,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:12:16,860 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started (with errors) in 6985ms - Started 275 of 331 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 91 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
15:12:17,001 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment email-servidores.war
15:12:17,241 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment email-servidores.war (runtime-name: email-servidores.war) in 252ms
15:12:17,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "email-servidores.war" (runtime-name: "email-servidores.war")
15:12:17,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."email-servidores.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./email-servidores
```

Thank you.

Marcos

**UPDATE**

It worked now. I added the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This has been extremely helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to creating a custom module and defining a dependency to that module is to just deploy the jar file to the application server (f.i. ufca.jar). Once the jar is deployed, you can simply declare a dependency to this deployment from your war-file using f.i. deployment.ufca.jar as the id.

In your war-file you can f.i. use the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to add the dependency, f.i. using

```
<dependencies>
  <module name="deployment.ufca.jar" />
</dependencies>
```

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: oh, I see that my answer is corrupted. I will edit it soon when my call is finished.

Comment: I didn't understand the f.i. part. Is this an entry in the MANIFEST.MF file? Could you update your answer again to include an example of how to declare the dependency in the war file?

Comment: Thank you. I think we're almost there. As you could se, my jar (ufca.jar) has a dependency on the module 'javax.faces.api' that was set when I created a module for my jar. But I'm having problems trying to specify this dependency in the 'jboss-deployment-structure-xml' file, that's why I'm getting the same errors I was getting before. Could you update your answer once again to add this dependency? Thank you once again.

Comment: ok, the dependencies of your jar must be declared in your jar, not the war. so add the dependencies to the MANIFEST.MF of your jar as a comma-separated list like this:

Dependencies: javaee.api,javax.faces.api

This is also explained in the class-loading documentation I've posted

Answer (score 0):

If really needed for technical reasons, it is possible to allow deployments to access your module classes thanks to such a part in configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <global-modules>
    <module name="br.edu.ufca" slot="main" />            
  </global-modules> 
</subsystem>
```

I typically use this way when publishing a JDBC driver, first for a DataSource of course, but also because when application code requires access to implementation classes.

If you want to share a large set of dependencies between multiple independent deployments, it is a good way to spare memory.